# How to rename columns in a table by using a table of old and new names in R (tidyverse)?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table with column names that I want to change based on a table with a column of the current names and a column of the replacement names.

As an example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
name_tbl <- enframe(names(mtcars), value = "old_names") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(new_names = paste0(old_names, sample(50:100, 1)))

name_tbl
#> # A tibble: 11 x 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>     name old_names new_names
#>    <int> <chr>     <chr>    
#>  1     1 mpg       mpg79    
#>  2     2 cyl       cyl57    
#>  3     3 disp      disp70   
#>  4     4 hp        hp57     
#>  5     5 drat      drat72   
#>  6     6 wt        wt88     
#>  7     7 qsec      qsec86   
#>  8     8 vs        vs66     
#>  9     9 am        am91     
#> 10    10 gear      gear71   
#> 11    11 carb      carb50
```

At this point, I would like to be able to do something like:

`mtcars %>% rename(name_tbl$old_names = name_tbl$new_names)`

however it of course does not work because rename expects named arguments.

I've looked all over and have not found a tidyverse method of doing this operation.  Is there some way to rename columns using a lookup table like this?

Currently I'm pivoting longer on everything and then left_joining the key table, however this is problematic because all columns have to be converted to the same type first, which is not easily undone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We `ungroup`, the 'name_tbl' and create a named vector or `list` and use `!!!` within `rename` to change the column names

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
v1 <- name_tbl %>% 
       ungroup %>%
       select(new_names, old_names) %>%
       deframe
mtcars %>% 
  rename(!!! v1)
```

-output

```
#                   mpg82 cyl96 disp93 hp94 drat74  wt58 qsec53 vs70 am79 gear81 carb83
#Mazda RX4          21.0     6    160  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4
#Mazda RX4 Wag      21.0     6    160  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4
#Datsun 710         22.8     4    108   93   3.85 2.320  18.61    1    1      4      1
#Hornet 4 Drive     21.4     6    258  110   3.08 3.215  19.44    1    0      3      1
#Hornet Sportabout  18.7     8    360  175   3.15 3.440  17.02    0    0      3      2
#Valiant            18.1     6    225  105   2.76 3.460  20.22    1    0      3      1
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for.  I see that rename(mtcars, v1) also works, the triple bangs aren't needed.  I like yours better as it's clearer that something special is happening.  Too bad that !!! wasn't documented in ?rename.  Is there any reason the !!! would be preferable for other reasons that I"m not encountering with this example?

Comment: For anyone wondering about the ungroup, it isn't necessary normally, it was just an artifact of my using rowwise() to get different random numbers for the new_names.

Comment: @jzadra I would `ungroup` after the grouping are done.  In this case it is `rowwise` and it may affect performance

Comment: yeah I tried to right away but SO makes you wait a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

One option with the addition of `stringr` could be:

```
mtcars %>%
 rename_with(~ str_replace_all(., setNames(name_tbl$new_names, name_tbl$old_names)), everything())

                    mpg81 cyl61 disp61 hp69 drat98  wt99 qsec87 vs87 am77 gear50 carb81
Mazda RX4            21.0     6  160.0  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4
Mazda RX4 Wag        21.0     6  160.0  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4
Datsun 710           22.8     4  108.0   93   3.85 2.320  18.61    1    1      4      1
Hornet 4 Drive       21.4     6  258.0  110   3.08 3.215  19.44    1    0      3      1
Hornet Sportabout    18.7     8  360.0  175   3.15 3.440  17.02    0    0      3      2
```